# How to Partially Answer My Own Question: Protocol

Tags: discussion, support, questions, specific-question

I have a question here: [Matplotlib: 3D Scatter plots not recognizing labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921559/matplotlib-3d-scatter-plots-not-recognizing-labels)

I got one answer that didn't work for me, but I then found a solution that mostly works, so I posted this as an answer. However, it is obviously not the best, as it doesn't totally solve the problem.

My question is: What do I do? I don't want to accept my answer yet because I want to see if a better one comes along, but I also don't want it to just get buried. What is the best thing to do in this case?

Comment: I should add that the original person who answered the question was kind enough to answer my issue in a comment on that answer. I feel kinda bad about not accepting his answer, but my answer is now the correct one.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Accept whatever answer answers the question completely as correct, even if it's your own. If you've posted your own partial answer, then later updated it to be fully correct, and nobody else posted a better, fully correct answer first, then accept your own.

Think from the point of view of somebody else with the same question as you finding your post; which answer would answer their question? That is the goal -- to provide the internet with a good source of information, not to distribute or gain reputation points on the site.

An answer not being accepted doesn't mean it's "wrong", it just means it's *probably* not the one that answers the question the best.<sup>†</sup> Upvotes and downvotes effectively rate other non-accepted answers, as well as the accepted one, and readers are both free to and capable of looking at the votes and reading other answers as well. So don't think that accepting one answer somehow invalidates the rest.

As for any concerns about "fairness" or feelings of "guilt" or whatever: Say thank you to the person that helped complete your answer in a comment. That's a nice, good thing to do. Then accept your own answer, since it is the most correct, as that is also the right thing to do. You've done your part, expressed your gratitude, and helped the internet. If the other poster's self-image is damaged by not receiving the green check mark and an extra 15 points, that is not your problem to solve, that's more an issue for him to reflect on in the shower or on the bus or something.

If the other person is an active contributing member, they will likely both understand and appreciate what I am describing here: Marking the most helpful answer as correct to help others as well as yourself. The user you are speaking of has posted 371 answers and has been a member for 3 years, I'd guess that he understands how it works.

---

<sup>†</sup> And, if many answers answer the question equally well, just pick your favorite or roll some dice: Only one can be accepted.

Comment: "it just means it's not the one that answers the question the best": That would be nice. Unfortunately, often it isn't because the asker is too hasty, never reconsiders as he learns more or better answers come, is out for the quick fix without learning, ... good answer.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes, it's an ideal situation that doesn't always happen. That's why it's good to see the *asker* come to meta with questions like this, and try to give those values to askers. It's the best we can do. If the question itself is useful and an answer other than the accepted one is more helpful, then over time (also ideally) the vote counts will reflect that.

Comment: "Accepted" means nothing more than "this one helped me most". It doesn't need to be right, accurate or best. Just the one that offered _that insight_ That solved it. Upvotes/downvotes are for right/wrong.